# QPix QPx_AcqRunSession does not preview the image being captured

Tags: 4d-database

We are upgrading our project to 4D v12 and our QPix plugin stopped showing us a preview of the image we are about to take. The image capture works just fine; the only problem is that the preview simply shows a white screen.

If I select the "Video Settings..." button I get a screen with a preview, so I know that it should be possible to get the preview.

This is a longshot; if you need any more information I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard back from Escape Tech Support and they claim that the issue is a bug in 4D v12. They are hoping for a fix in 4D v12.1.

Answer (score 0):

MrHen, I'm glad you got an answer, even if it isn't a very satisfying on.  Just so you know there isn't much in the way of 4D activity on SO (and most of what there is is for an unrelated application). If you have other issues I'd recommend the NUG or the official 4D forums.

4D NUG (networked users group) mailing list:
You can search it here: kb.4d.com
Join it (4D Tech) here so you can post: lists.4d.com/mailman/listinfo/4d_tech

Official 4D forums:
www.4d.com/us/community/forum.html

Comment: Yeah, I know about the NUG. I am planning on posting any 4D related questions here anyway just in case it saves someone some Googling later. :)

Answer (score 0):

the NUG is little outdated, http://forums.4d.fr, is the place to go. There you can get in touch with the 4D headquarter instead with marketing on the NUG. :)